# How to configure Filezilla server on an Azure VM?

Tags: firewall, ftp, azure, filezilla

I want to create a Filezilla server on Azure VM. And for that I have configured basic settings on the server. And now I'm successfully able to connect to the server via local network (If I test on the server via Filezilla client).

But the real issue starts when I tried to connect the Filezilla server from an outside network.

I have checked some of the solutions from the internet and tried to add few inbound rules and also added some network related configuration on the Azure vm (As shown in the image).

> [image]

> [image]

But still whenever I try to connect to the Filezilla server it shows me this error.

> [image]

Does anyone have idea about this? Or did I miss any firewall or Azure settings?

Comment: Your allow rule does not allow traffic on port 21 despite the fact the server is running on that port.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Ramhound . But I do have added the inbound rule for port 21 (TCP) as I have attached the screenshots (Both in Azure and VM's Firewall). Do I have to add that rule anywhere else?

Comment: Within the screenshot you provided, the FileZilla rule you highlighted does not allow port 21.  The rule that does allow traffic on that port does not apply to FileZilla.

Comment: @Ramhound I have tried to add the rule 21 to FileZilla as you have suggested but despite adding that rule it is still not working. Do you have any other idea what might be causing issue in this situation?

Comment: I have lots of ideas but it would require far more information, then you have provided, and I am not mentally up to listing each individual bit of information.  It's not clear the reason you are forward port traffic to your public ip address instead of your intranet address of your server.  Are you being an CGNAT?